# Rigs are deforming strangely

Tags: rigging

Earlier today, I had some trouble because of the rigs moving other parts. Thankfully that was solved, but now I have another problem (as you can see, I'm pretty new to rigging people). I want my limbs to bend sharply, except they're curving at the joints. How do I solve this? I suppose it involves something with weight painting?

[image]

Comment: again, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Ok, please provide help. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6505" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6505/)

Answer (score 1):

The lower arm mesh is influenced by the upper arm bone. You need to do several things:

- First put your *Armature* modifier above the *Subsurf*, enable *Preserve Volume*, plus I don't think you need 2 for *Viewport Subdivisions* but it's a detail.
- Your topology needs to be aligned on your bones and also you need to make sure that it will allow your elbow to bend smoothly, so move your elbow edge and bevel it.
- Select the armature then the object, switch to *Weight Paint* mode, in the N panel > Tool, choose Blend > Subtract or Mix depending on if you want to subtract or add influence, in the Options only keep *2D Falloff* so that you'll be able to paint through the mesh.
- Select the upper arm and paint its influence so that it doesn't cross the elbow, same for the lower arm.
- Move your bones to test.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! you are a true hero :)